# S3 Flysystem returns file key, but size method throws "Not Found"

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3

I'm able to get and list out files for a particular key/directory in S3 using the league\flysystem storage methods:

```php
$s3 = \Storage::disk('s3');
$files = $s3->files($cp->s3DirectoryPrefix);
```

returns:

```php
array( 0 => "content_properties/503a3468-d660-44f8-9edd-f10cd812f346/submaster_primary.mp4")
```

However, when I try and get the size for the file returned, it throws an exception.

```php
$size = $s3->size($files[0]);
```

```php
League \ Flysystem \ FileNotFoundException
File not found at path: content_properties/503a3468-d660-44f8-9edd-f10cd812f346/submaster_primary.mp4
```

This only occurs on a certain bucket. Other buckets the exception is not thrown, and the size of the object/file is returned properly.

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong? Some certain setting on the bucket?

Accessing the object via the CLI with the same credentials work just fine:

```py
aws s3api head-object --bucket content-data-app-private --key content_properties/503a3468-d660-44f8-9edd-f10cd812f346/submaster_primary.mp4

aws s3api get-object --bucket content-data-app-private --key content_properties/503a3468-d660-44f8-9edd-f10cd812f346/submaster_primary.mp4 ~/Downloads/submaster_primary.mp4
```

These return proper info/content. So what is happening in Flysystem where it can retrieve a listing of the files, but not methods on the file/object itself?

Comment: You need to give the full path of the bucket... is "content_properties" the main "bucket" ?

Comment: Not a relevant comment, as the adapter returns the object key for the object within the bucket.

Comment: “Not a relevant comment”, really ? The size function in ANY S3 PHP adapter will require the full path of the object, good luck with your question.

Answer (score -1):

i don't know if this work on s3, so you may try

```
    $datas = collect(Storage::disk('s3')->files($cp->s3DirectoryPrefix))
                        ->mapWithKeys(function($file) {
                            return [$file => Storage::disk('s3')->size($file)];
                        });
```

Comment: Not relevant to the issue. As stated above, the size() commands works on objects in other buckets, but not this particular bucket.